# Java compiler not checking IF ELSE condition beforehand (or at least I think that is what's happening...)

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a simple class file called *File.java* with 3 functions in it: *createFile*, *writeContent* and the obligatory *main* function as a driver:

```
import java.io.*;

class CreateFile {

    public static boolean createFile(File file, String fileName) throws IOException {
        if (file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println(fileName + ": File created successfully!");
            return false;
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileName + ": File already existing!");
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void writeContent(String fileName, String fileContent, boolean append) throws IOException {
        if (append = false) {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, false));
        } else {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
        }
        writer.write(fileContent);
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "file.txt";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        boolean append = createFile(file, fileName);
        String fileContent = "Hello, this is a test";
        writeContent(fileName, fileContent, append);
    }
}
```

The trouble is with the function writeContent, which is called in the last line. There is a basic if condition, checking whether the writing process needs to append to the file, or not (I know this is not necessary, but I am still testing, so bear with me).

I get an error saying the compiler can't find the symbol *writer*, meaning that the BufferedWriter *writer* is created *before* checking the if condition. This is precisely what I don't get: Why isn't the if condition executed beforehand?

If I include the write commands in the if and the else statement it works beautifully, but that causes code redundancy which is what I am trying to circumvent:

```
    public static void writeContent(String fileName, String fileContent, boolean append) throws IOException {
        if (append = false) {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, false));
            writer.write(fileContent);
            writer.close();
        } else {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
            writer.write(fileContent);
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

I am sure I am simply obtuse to something fundamental & simple - would you mind giving me a hint here?

Comment: `if (append = false) {` should be `if (append == false) {` (two equals signs). To avoid the problem just write `if(!append)`

Comment: `if (append = false) ` is an assignation, and always will be true. you wanted to write `if (!append)` instead

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't seem to be the only flaw in my code, through, since the error remains...

Comment: I would recommend declaring `BufferedWriter` outside of your `if` conditions and just assign it a value within them.

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to explicitly compare to `true` and `false` in Java.

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```
if (append = false) {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, false));
} else {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
}
```

Change to:

```
BufferedWriter writer;
if (append == false) {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, false));
} else {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
}
```

If you create variable inside braces {} it's scope is limited to them.
So, you should create `writer` outside `if`, because you use it later.

Answer (score 4):

You assigned `append = false` instead of compared `append == false`.
Better style is not to compare with `true` or `false`.

```
    if (!append) {
```

Or simply drop the if statement:

```
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, append));
```

Comment: The second part does solve the problem, incidentally. But the main problem (the compilation error) is with the fact that `writer` is out of scope when used later. Which is answered in the linked duplicate, to be fair.